# open jpa - capture logging using log4j.xml

Tags: java, log4j, apache-camel, openjpa

I am trying to set my log4j.xml up so that it captures the sql queries generated by JPA. My first step was to enable JPA logging.

I did this by adding the following to my persistence.xml file....

```
       <property name="openjpa.Log" value="openjpa.jdbc.MetaData=TRACE"/>
       <property name="openjpa.Log" value="openjpa.jdbc.JDBC=TRACE"/>
       <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE"/>
```

Straight after I did that I started getting output on the console...

```
6032  camel  TRACE  [Camel (camel) thread #0 - file://src/inbox/items/] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 272983323, conn 752449949> [1 ms] spent
6077  camel  TRACE  [Camel (camel) thread #0 - file://src/inbox/items/] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 272983323, conn 1005639669> executing prepstmnt 1497874461 INSERT INTO stg_import_payload (id, FILENAME, LOAD_DATETIME, IMPORT_PAYLOAD_BODY, IMPORT_PAYLOAD_TYPE, ...
```

But I can't grab this output in my log files. I have something not set up correctly in log4j.xml. Appreciate if you could have a look and help out. Here are my settings...

```
 <appender name="DatabaseLog" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/var/log/myproject/database.log"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5MB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm:ss.SSS},%m%n"/>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
      <param name="levelMin" value="TRACE" />
      <param name="levelMax" value="WARN" />
    </filter>
  </appender>

  <logger name="openjpa.jdbc.SQL" additivity="false">
     <appender-ref ref="DatabaseLog"/>
  </logger>   

  <root>
    <priority value="INFO" />
  </root>
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the following post ...

[How do I configure OpenJPA SQL logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733408/how-do-i-configure-openjpa-sql-logging)

which gave me a huge hint on what needed to be done I resolved this issue.

In log4j.xml i needed

```
<logger name="openjpa.jdbc.SQL" additivity="false">
 <appender-ref ref="DatabaseLog"/>
</logger>    

<category name="openjpa.jdbc.SQL">
        <level value="TRACE" />
</category>
```

And then in persistence.xml you need to add...

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="log4j"/>
```